# Keep the indexes on an array

Tags: php, indexing, array-map

How can I change the following code so the `keys`of `$result` will not get overwritten by `[0], [1], ...` but instead be kept the way they were?

```
$result = array_map(function($key, $value) {

    return preg_replace("/(".$_POST['keyword'].")/i", "<mark>$1</mark>", $value);

}, array_keys($result), $result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_walk`([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)) instead of `array_map` it will preserve keys:

```php
array_walk($result, function(&$key, $value) {
    $key = preg_replace("/(".$_POST['keyword'].")/i", "<mark>$1</mark>", $value);
}, $result);
```